# ARR does not send Response.Flush content to client

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-10, arr

In some **classic asp** applications here we use the `Response.Flush` to immediately send content from server to the client, at least that's how used to work with **IIS7**.

Now that we have two servers and a proxy-reverse server using **ARR** to load balance the requests (all 3 running **IIS10**), for some reason the `Response.Flush` method does not work as used to. It looks like the response is sent to the **ARR** whom wait until the response server send all the content before giving it to the client.

This is an issue mainly when the remaining content takes some time to be processed.

Is there any config I should know about?

Comment: try to use Response.End().  Using Response.Flush() & Response.Close() won't correctly close.

Comment: But what about the rest of the code that needs to be processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a response buffer threshold setting in ARR Server Proxy Settings that defaults to 256 KB.

If you set it to 0 (KB), it must be work as you expect.

This is a machine scope setting so **you need to have administrative privileges** to modify it.

You can change the setting by running following command in a command prompt

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/proxy /minResponseBuffer:"0"  /commit:apphost
```

or by using IIS Manager's GUI:

- Open IIS Manager
- Click server's name on the menu
- Double click **Application Request Routing Cache**
- Click **Server Proxy Settings** on **Actions** pane.
- Scroll to **Buffer Setting** group.
- Change **Response buffer threshold (KB)** setting.
- Click **Apply** on **Actions** pane.

Comment: Thanks, I sent this info to the server admin, this really did the job. I was upset things were working differently between environments (dev and production).